# vasm for Motorola 68000 cannot assign the distance between two labels to a symbol

Tags: assembly, 68000

Vasm should support calculating the distance between two labels by subtracting `end - start` to get their difference, but I'm getting assembler errors when I try.

I do have this simple example code, where I create an AMIGA Copper-List which is stored in the code between two labels:

```
CLstart:
  dc.w      COLOR00,$0000
  dc.w      $780f,                      $fffe
  dc.w      COLOR00,$0f00
  dc.w      $d70f,$fffe
  dc.w      COLOR00,$0fb0
  dc.w      $ffff,$fffe
CLend:
```

To have it flexible, I like to have the assembler calculate the size of the Copper-List for me so I don't need to re-calculate it by hand every time I change it.

So I do this:

```
;Sonstige Label
Execbase    = 4
Chip        = 2                                  ; Ramtype: Chip-RAM anfordern

CLsize = CLend - CLstart
;*** Vorprogramm

;Speicher für Copper-List anfordern

Start:
  move.l    Execbase,a6                  
  moveq     #CLsize, d0                   ;Parameter für AllocMem setzen
```

So I calculate CLsize with the vasm directive
 =

I try to compile it with this line:

```
vasmm68k_mot -m68000 -Fhunk -linedebug -o e:\Amiga\Assembler\Testing\mywork\build\copperdemo.o e:\Amiga\Assembler\Testing\mywork\copperdemo.s
```

And I get the following errors:

```
error 10 in line 40 of "e:\Amiga\Assembler\Testing\mywork\copperdemo.s": number or identifier expected
>  moveq     #CLsize, d0                   ;Parameter für AllocMem setzen

error 9 in line 40 of "e:\Amiga\Assembler\Testing\mywork\copperdemo.s": instruction not supported on selected architecture
>  moveq     #CLsize, d0                   ;Parameter für AllocMem setzen
```

So the first error is actually what I do not understand. Obviously `CLsize` is not getting calculated and therefore the Assembler does not know what to do with `CLsize` as a number in this particular line.

The line next to it works as expected:

```
moveq    #Chip,d1
```

I tried different things, but do not understand why the calculation of the two labels do not assign it to the symbol and why I cannot use the symbol then in the `moveq` expression.

I moved the calculation to the end, so that all labels are defined, but does not work.
I tried to use an `equ` statement, but this doesn't work either:

```
CLsize equ CLend - CLstart
```

Comment: Okay, found the first issue ...
`moveq #CLsize, d0 ;Parameter für AllocMem setzen`
The space before d0 is actually not allowed. However I now get this error for all occurences where I want to write CLsize to a reqister with moveq (three of them): 
`error 2025: absolute value expected`

Comment: You seem to have a habit of including spaces in the worst places - vasm doesn't like that. Remove the spaces from your expressions and you should be fine (or compile with the *-phxass* option)

Comment: Yes you are right, I like to use spaces to make it more readable ... I made my live even more miserable, after trying without spaces I introduced a typo (CLsize=CLend-Clstart). And surprisingly that also did not work ... :-( .
Thanks for the update.

Comment: If I had an assembler that choked on the space in `moveq     #CLsize, d0`, I'd get a new assembler.  That seems like terribly bad syntax design to not allow spaces before the comma between operands, since it's still pretty trivial to parse.  And to detect syntax errors, it still has to check for any non-symbol character, not just scan for the next comma once it starts a symbol.  Oh, a space there begins a comment, but not the space before the first operand?  Insane.

Comment: This is kept for compatibility with stoneage assemblers from the Amiga, to support source code compatibility. One of those actually interpreted anything after a space as a comment.
You can just turn it of -space and thats it.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, here is the answer (after a day of wasted time) for others to understand:

CLsize = CLend - CLstart  does not work, as vasm by default will ignore everything after the first space (CLend here).

And then the error message makes sense, because CLend is a long value and does not fit into moveq operation (only 8bit value is allowed).

The correct formula would be

CLsize=CLend-CLstart

Or you can use the option -spaces to change the behaviour of the assembler to ignore spaces and only use ; as comment marker.